# How to append content to an array in a php file

Tags: php

I have a PHP file a configuration file coming from a [Yii2](https://yiiframework.com) message translation file which contains this:

```
return[

   'Juventus' => '尤文图斯',
   'Milan' => '米兰',
];
```

I want to append values to the array so i can get something like below:

```
return[

  'Juventus' => '尤文图斯',
  'Milan' => '米兰',
  'Chelsea' => '切尔西',
];
```

Note: Another element added to the array
But then below is the result i got rather

```
return[

  'Juventus' => '尤文图斯',
  'Milan' => '米兰',
];

'Chelsea' => '切尔西',
```

The new element rather was added outside of the array 
I'm using file_put_contents() to append the file like this..

```
file_put_contents($file, "'Chelsea' => '切尔西'," . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

How can i solve the problem or what's the better away of doing this.. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file, insert the line you want before the `]` line, and write the result back to the file.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
str_replace('];', "'Chelsea' => '切尔西'," . PHP_EOL . '];', $contents);
file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

It would probably be better if you made it a data file instead of a PHP script. You can format using `json_encode()` or `serialize()`.

Comment: thanks for your help, you're right it will be better using data file but the php script is a config file and must be left the way it is